# How to disable packages for specific filetypes in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

For example, I want to disable Emmet package in Markdown files. Is that possible? I've been searching in Sublime docs (official and unofficial) and Google and I haven't found any info.